# How can I generate an array of icon names to use as options in a Vuetify v-autocomplete statement?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, material-design, vuetify.js

My application relies on icons for decorating data that's inserted as a link item into the side navigation by the end user. The current icon libraries installed are as such:

Located in the head of vue.blade.app (the view file that Laravel is entering my Vue Single Page Application (SPA) from)

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/font-awesome@4.x/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

There is a form in the app where the user can create the data, and they have the option of choosing an icon for it. If none is chosen, an in-code default is used. Here is the code for the select statement in that form:

```
<v-autocomplete 
    label="Icon" 
    persistent-hint 
    hint="If no icon is selected, a default will be used."
    :items="testIconsData"
    auto-select-first 
    chips 
    clearable
 >
    <template slot="item" slot-scope="data">
        <v-row no-gutters>
            <v-col>
                <v-icon>{{data.item}}</v-icon>
            </v-col>
            <v-col>{{data.item}}</v-col>
        </v-row>
    </template>
</v-autocomplete>
```

(Note: My v-autocomplete has a v-model, but it's not necessary to show it here.)

The testIconData is a temporary array of icon names located in the same file where the form is stored.

```
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                testIconsData: [
                    'mdi-phone',
                    'mdi-ab-testing',
                    'mdi-access-point',
                    'mdi-format-clear'
                ]
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

Here is a screenshot of the final result:

[The select statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBUUI.png)

Rather than using the testIconsData array, I would prefer to read from the libraries (shown in the first code block) to create an array of all renderable icons that I can then apply to the v-autocomplete.

This would save time and ensure that the options are renderable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to see if these libraries provide and maintain a list of their icons. For example, Material Design Icons provide a JSON file of their icons on [GitHub](https://github.com/Templarian/MaterialDesign/blob/master/meta.json). Font Awesome also provide some metadata on their [GitHub](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/tree/master/metadata). You can extract the lists from these files using javascript either statically or dynamically if you want your app to automatically include new icons.